# Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i am using ASP.NET MVC
i config truthly  database
but it says[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi9LA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually an error with your entity framework while trying to perform a database operation. Here is a modified example from TechFunda showing how to see what your entity validation errors are so that you can fix them. If you look at the errorMessage varaible while debugging it should tell you what your actual error is.

```
public ActionResult ReceiveParameters(PersonalDetails pd)
    {
        try
        {
            //Entity Framework Code You are executing
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ee)
        {
            foreach (var error in ee.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach(var thisError in error.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    var errorMessage = thisError.ErrorMessage;
                }                    
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Source: [TechFunda Article](http://techfunda.com/howto/515/getting-entityvalidationerrors)